# Creating nested objects from a pseudo-hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{
    level: 0,
    data: 'A',
}, {
    level: 1,
    data: 'B',
}, {
    level: 1,
    data: 'C',
}, {
    level: 2,
    data: 'D',
}, {
    level: 3,
    data: 'E',
}, {
    level: 1,
    data: 'F',
}]
```

Which can be visualized as:

```
A
  B
  C
    D
      E
  F
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
{
    data: 'A',
    children: [{
        data: 'B',
    }, {
        data: 'C',
        children: [{
            data: 'D',
            children: [{
                data: 'E',
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        level: 1,
        data: 'F',
    }]
}
```

Where items are effectively turned into a tree, by their `level`. There is only one top-level element.

I can't really see how to do this. I think I want some kind of stack-based solution, but I haven't managed to work it out.

Comment: You can't really. Level 2 goes under what? F, C, B ? There's just not enough info to build a tree

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: It's all about the order of the elements. See the visualization I added in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, that was easier than expected:

```
var stack = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var toAdd = {
        data: item.data,
        children: []
    };
    stack[item.level] = toAdd;
    if(item.level > 0)
        stack[item.level - 1].children.push(toAdd);
}

var tree = stack[0];
console.log(tree);
```